# Why do we add $\delta_i \Delta Y_{t-i}$ in order to make an ADF test?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

Let's say we have the ADF test for no constant and no deterministic trend. So the regression model is $$\Delta Y_t=\delta Y_{t-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \delta_i \Delta Y_{t-i}+Z_t$$ according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test.

My question is, why do we add $\delta_i \Delta Y_{t-i}$ (which are terms of difference) in order to approximate an ARMA structure of errors, instead of $Y_{t-2}, Y_{t-3},\dots$ and so on?